# how to build a full Stack ecommerce app with 2 separated projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authorization, single-sign-on

I have two separated projects (dashboard- website) Which these are contain their own node module and package.Json, I want to link them through the form so the form allows only the admin to sign in to the dashboard, and if it user go back to the website.

this is the website directory

[image]

and this is the dashboard directory

[image]

the form is inside the dashboard directory

[image]

Could anyone help me and tell me the main plan to do that?